# Sequelize bulkCreate() returns NULL value for primary key

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am writing rest using node, sequelize as ORM for mySQL.
I am using bulkCreate function to create record in bulk. But in response it is returning **null** for primary key value.

Model

```
sequelize.define('category', {
    cat_id:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field:'cat_id',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique:true
    },
    cat_name:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'cat_name',
        defaultValue:null
    }
});
```

Bulk Create operation :

```
var data = [
        {
            'cat_name':'fashion'
        },
        {
            'cat_name':'food'
        }
    ];

    orm.models.category.bulkCreate(data)
    .then(function(response){
        res.json(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        res.json(error);
    })
```

response :

```
[
  {
    "cat_id": null,
    "cat_name": "fashion",
    "created_at": "2016-01-29T07:39:50.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-29T07:39:50.000Z"
  },
  {
    "cat_id": null,
    "cat_name": "food",
    "created_at": "2016-01-29T07:39:50.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-29T07:39:50.000Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should set the `returning` option:

```
Model.bulkCreate(values, {returning: true})
```

Comment: But only in postgres and mssql

Comment: It will not update the `values` array. It will return a new array.

Comment: Hey I am using postgresql 14 but it didn't work for me @Adam

Answer (score 27):

Tested in MySQL:

```
Model.bulkCreate(values, { individualHooks: true })
```

Comment: { individualHooks: true } is wildly misleading, at least in Sequelize 3.  I just traced it and it reverts to doing individual saves!  It's NOT BULK!  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since his question is related to the mysql.

Comment: I tested this in MySQL and it is currently not working

Answer (score 8):

```
var data = [
    {
        'cat_name':'fashion'
    },
    {
        'cat_name':'food'
    }
];

Model.bulkCreate(data)
.then(function() {

 //(if you try to immediately return the Model after bulkCreate, the ids may all show up as 'null')
  return Model.findAll()
})
.then(function(response){
    res.json(response);
})
.catch(function(error){
    res.json(error);
})
```

Comment: Good use of comments in your example. Nice job on your first answer. Welcome (another woman, YAY) to the Community ;)

Answer (score 4):

> The success handler is passed an array of instances, but please notice that these may not completely represent the state of the rows in the DB. This is because MySQL and SQLite do not make it easy to obtain back automatically generated IDs and other default values in a way that can be mapped to multiple records. To obtain Instances for the newly created values, you will need to query for them again.
>   http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that doesn't work in the latest version. They explain why here:
http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

note that the description specifically mentions mysql. You'll have to query for them. (example includes `var _ = require('lodash');`

```
var cat = rm.models.category;
cat.bulkCreate(data)
 .then(function (instances) {
    var names = _.map(instances, function (inst) {
      return inst.cat_name;
    });
    return cat.findAll({where: {cat_name: {$in: names}}); 
 })
 .then(function(response){
    res.json(response);
 })
 .catch(function(error){
    res.json(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation: please notice that these may not completely represent the state of the rows in the DB. This is because MySQL and SQLite do not make it easy to obtain back automatically generated IDs and other default values in a way that can be mapped to multiple records. To obtain Instances for the newly created values, you will need to query for them again.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate

But you can pass an option to make it return the id

```
orm.models.category.bulkCreate(data, { returning: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [{
   'cat_name':'fashion'
  },
  {
   'cat_name':'food'
  }
 ];

orm.models.category.bulkCreate(data,{individualHooks: true})
 .then(function(response){
   res.json(response);
 })
 .catch(function(error){
   res.json(error);
 });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.