# Sequelize: bulkCreate not exiting after insert

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I am trying to insert records using **bulkCreate** but it does not exit after this method is called. Please have a look below:

This is the class Schema to create Modal

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import {database, username, password, options} from './config.json';

class Schema {
    constructor() {
        this.sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, options);
    }

    bucketModal(){
        return this.sequelize.define('S3bucketFiles', {
            BucketName: Sequelize.STRING,
            FileName: Sequelize.STRING,
            IsInUse: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            BucketType: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
            {
                timestamps: false
            });
    }
}

export const AwsSchema = new Schema();
```

Following is the class in which I am inserting bulk records into the database:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import {database, username, password, options} from './config.json';
import {AwsSchema} from './schema';

class Aws {
    constructor() {
        this.sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, options);
        this.bucket = AwsSchema.bucketModal();
    }

    /**
     * Save data
     * @param data
     */
   create(data) {
       return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(this.bucket.bulkCreate(data));
       })
    }
}

export const AwsDb = new Aws();
```

Here problem is with the **create()** function here.

```
create(data) {
           return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(this.bucket.bulkCreate(data));
           })
        }
```

You can see I am trying to return Promise, but bulkCreate does not exit. Output is shown something like this:

```
37571438059.png',2),(N'customerud',N'bug426_CA5592_63600919dfdf93388220.jpg',2);
```

new line is not shown here, cursor is blinking above and when all the data is saved then it does not exit.

If I just write the following code below:

```
create(data) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(5);
        })
    }
```

Now the script is exiting and I can see the following output which looks good to me:

```
data records
amuk@amuk:~
```

So I just want to know is there any way to exit from **bulkCreate** or something is not correct in the code?

Comment: When you are using `resolve(5)` code exit successfully, it means `resolve(this.bucket.bulkCreate(data))` not resolving promise successfully. Looks like `this.bucket.bulkCreate(data)` not returning `true` in every case and promise not resolving. Can you check what is result of `this.bucket.bulkCreate(data)`? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079286/sequelize-bulkcreate-returns-null-value-for-primary-key also.

Comment: Instead of breaking the aws files into chunks I send everything in bulk to sequelize method and it worked