# Sequelize bulkCreate inside transaction dont return id

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert data inside transaction. And it looks like this:

```
let trx = await psql.transaction();
  let z = { 
    name: 'name',
  }
  const result = await psql.MyTable.create(z, {transaction: trx});
```

When I am trying to seed id of inserted data everything works fine:

```
console.log(result.id) //Returns correct id
```

But if I change inserting method `create` to `bulkCreate`(I need to insert multiple data) my code will change like that:

```
let trx = await psql.transaction();
let z = [{ 
    name: 'name',
}]
const result = await psql.MyTable.bulkCreate(z, {transaction: trx});
```

But in this case it returns ids as `null`

```
console.log(result[0].id) // null
```

All other values returns correct.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079286/sequelize-bulkcreate-returns-null-value-for-primary-key), it has to do with returning a column with default value

Comment: @JasonAthanasoglou thanks so much